# Can't upload APK file to google play because it's using restricted APIs

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-permissions

When I try to upload an APK file to **google play** I get the following **error**:

[image]

I can't find any source talking about this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Signature level permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) from the Google Play Store app:

```
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.android
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.androidsecure
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.sierra
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.sierraqa
android.permission.com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.sierrasandbox
```

You cannot use them.

Also see [Security Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error show that you can't use GOOGLE_AUTO permission. so you can delete it in AndroidManifest. then upload try agagin.Hope help you.